# Where in Gauss's works does he derive "Gauss's Law"?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, electricity

Where in Gauss's works does he derive "Gauss's Law"? Or is "Gauss's Law" named after Gauss for a different reason?

Comment: You can see the post [history of Gauss law](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68075/history-of-gauss-law) and the link to [DIVERGENCE THEOREM or GAUSS'S THEOREM](http://jeff560.tripod.com/d.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The law was first¹ formulated by Joseph Louis Lagrange in 1773,² followed by Carl Friedrich Gauss in 1813,³ both in the context of the attraction of ellipsoids.

<sup>Notes
¹ [Pierre Duhem](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Pierre_Maurice_Marie_Duhem.aspx#1)'s [*Leçons sur l'électricité et le magnétisme* (liv. 1, chap. 4, p. 22-23)](https://archive.org/stream/leonssurllec01duheuoft#page/22/mode/2up) shows that Lagrange has priority over Gauss. Others after Gauss discovered "Gauss's Law," too.
² Lagrange, "[Sur l'attraction des sphéroïdes elliptiques](https://books.google.com/books?id=4XkAAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA619)" , *Mémoires de l'Académie de Berlin*, p. 125; 1773.
³ Gauss (C.-F.) , [*Theoria attractionis corporum sphœroidicorum ellipticorum homogeneorum methodo nova tractata*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0TxeAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA3) (Gauss, *Werke*, t. V, p. 1). Gauss mentions Newton's related [*Principia* proposition XCI](https://archive.org/stream/newtonspmathema00newtrich#page/n243/mode/2up) regarding finding the force exerted by a sphere on a point anywhere along an axis passing through the spehere.</sup>

<sup>(source: [my recent edits on the "'Gauss's' Law" page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gauss%27s_law&type=revision&diff=732846510&oldid=726736706))</sup>